# Issue when user clicks Adaptive Card to invoke Task Module in the channel

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

When the user clicks on the Adaptive Card to invoke Task Module in the iOS Teams client, there is an error. The Adaptive Card works well with other types of clients, like Mac, and Browsers.

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Bot sent the following Adaptive Card to a channel according to the user's input.

```
{
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
   "version":"1.3",
   "fallbackText":"This card requires Adaptive Cards v1.2 support to be rendered properly.",
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"ColumnSet",
         "columns":[
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "text":"**Query:**",
                     "size":"Medium",
                     "weight":"Bolder",
                     "wrap":false
                  }
               ],
               "width":"48px"
            },
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "text":"sales today",
                     "size":"Medium",
                     "wrap":true
                  }
               ],
               "width":"auto"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"Container",
         "id":"table",
         "items":[
            {
               "type":"Container",
               "bleed":true,
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"ColumnSet",
                     "columns":[
                        {
                           "type":"Column",
                           "width":"auto",
                           "bleed":true,
                           "items":[
                              {
                                 "type":"TextBlock",
                                 "text":"No Data Found: We understood what you meant, however we didn't find any data matching your query. If you believe this is an error, please **report** this issue.",
                                 "horizontalAlignment":"left",
                                 "wrap":"true"
                              }
                           ],
                           "selectAction":{
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"column",
                              "data":{
                                 "msteams":{
                                    "type":"task/fetch"
                                 },
                                 "action_source":"report_issue",
                                 "id":"report_issue_invoke",
                                 "message_type":"no_data_found",
                                 "message":"No data found",
                                 "query_id":"q_7aGLqUYvSEWw1rjAbBiXMw",
                                 "user_id":"29:18Ly6dqUHd5j1HwXtx7z8qsndhqYOSc22UzQehulpOcIHLUcXAoJR0w2evYTwhFHFXaG5fEyYrZwFHZyO0PqRdQ"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

2. The user can click on the text to invoke a Task Module dialogue to fill in the feedback content. Then there will be an error thrown out if the user is using the iOS Teams client(Other types of clients are working well, like Mac, Android, and Chrome, Firefox, Safari browsers):

Following is the error stack:

```
/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/bin/python3.9 /Users/liming/Dev/Projects/chata/autoql-teams-bot/app.py
Running in Dev configuration
current env is:DEV
APP_ID is:acec457a-326b-43f1-9b38-724baaeb0057
======== Running on http://localhost:3978 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)

 [on_turn_error] unhandled error: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1293, in _deserialize
    found_value = key_extractor(attr, attr_desc, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1064, in rest_key_extractor
    return working_data.get(key)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
    return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 91, in receive_activity_internal
    raise error
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 89, in receive_activity_internal
    return await next_middleware.on_turn(context, call_next_middleware)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/show_typing_middleware.py", line 96, in on_turn
    result = await logic()
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 84, in call_next_middleware
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
    return await callback(context)
  File "/Users/liming/Dev/Projects/chata/autoql-teams-bot/bots/dialog_bot.py", line 42, in on_turn
    await super().on_turn(turn_context)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 78, in on_turn
    invoke_response = await self.on_invoke_activity(turn_context)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/teams/teams_activity_handler.py", line 154, in on_invoke_activity
    deserializer_helper(
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/serializer_helper.py", line 28, in deserializer_helper
    return deserializer(msrest_cls.__name__, dict_to_deserialize)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1233, in __call__
    return self._deserialize(target_obj, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1299, in _deserialize
    value = self.deserialize_data(raw_value, attr_desc['type'])
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1468, in deserialize_data
    return self._deserialize(obj_type, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1303, in _deserialize
    raise_with_traceback(DeserializationError, msg, err)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py", line 51, in raise_with_traceback
    raise error.with_traceback(exc_traceback)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1293, in _deserialize
    found_value = key_extractor(attr, attr_desc, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1064, in rest_key_extractor
    return working_data.get(key)
msrest.exceptions.DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1293, in _deserialize
    found_value = key_extractor(attr, attr_desc, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1064, in rest_key_extractor
    return working_data.get(key)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
    return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 91, in receive_activity_internal
    raise error
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 89, in receive_activity_internal
    return await next_middleware.on_turn(context, call_next_middleware)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/show_typing_middleware.py", line 96, in on_turn
    result = await logic()
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 84, in call_next_middleware
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
    return await callback(context)
  File "/Users/liming/Dev/Projects/chata/autoql-teams-bot/bots/dialog_bot.py", line 42, in on_turn
    await super().on_turn(turn_context)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 78, in on_turn
    invoke_response = await self.on_invoke_activity(turn_context)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/teams/teams_activity_handler.py", line 154, in on_invoke_activity
    deserializer_helper(
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/serializer_helper.py", line 28, in deserializer_helper
    return deserializer(msrest_cls.__name__, dict_to_deserialize)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1233, in __call__
    return self._deserialize(target_obj, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1299, in _deserialize
    value = self.deserialize_data(raw_value, attr_desc['type'])
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1468, in deserialize_data
    return self._deserialize(obj_type, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1303, in _deserialize
    raise_with_traceback(DeserializationError, msg, err)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py", line 51, in raise_with_traceback
    raise error.with_traceback(exc_traceback)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1293, in _deserialize
    found_value = key_extractor(attr, attr_desc, data)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1064, in rest_key_extractor
    return working_data.get(key)
msrest.exceptions.DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/integration/aiohttp_channel_service_exception_middleware.py", line 20, in aiohttp_error_middleware
    response = await handler(request)
  File "/Users/liming/Dev/Projects/chata/autoql-teams-bot/app.py", line 158, in messages
    invoke_response = await CONFIG.ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 451, in process_activity
    return await self.process_activity_with_identity(activity, identity, logic)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 493, in process_activity_with_identity
    await self.run_pipeline(context, logic)
  File "/Users/liming/venv/autoql-teams-bot/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 133, in run_pipeline
    await self.on_turn_error(context, error)
  File "/Users/liming/Dev/Projects/chata/autoql-teams-bot/app.py", line 111, in on_error
    await utilities.send_message_with_log(context, Activity("The bot encountered an error or bug."))
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

[Scenario 1: It displays an error: "Something went wrong. Please try again"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAF8u.jpg)

[Scenario 2: It displays an error: "Something went wrong. Please try again"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylDtL.png)

The root cause is the data transferred from iOS client contain a parameter “tab_entity_id” with 0 length string value to the bot. This value will cause the error  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` This error/exception was thrown out inside MS python library file msrest/serialzation.py, before the logic goes into our bot.

This error comes before the logic entering the bot. We are not able to fix it.

The file serialization.py is part of package msrest. The msrest package is provided by MS for Azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrest/msrest.serialization?view=azure-python

[file serialization.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8WEc.png)

Here are the screenshots:

This screenshot shows the exception was thrown out at line 1064 in file serialization.py in the console.

[the exception was thrown out at line 1064 in file serialization.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj0GH.png)

This screenshot shows the parameter value is 0 size string just before the exception was generated in line 1064 in file serialization.py

[the parameter value is 0 size string just before the exception was generated in line 1064 in file serialization.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ojDP.png)

This screenshot shows the value of “tab_entity_id” from iOS client is 0 length string.

[the value of “tab_entity_id” from iOS client is 0 length string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbwHS.png)

I confirmed this issue can be reproduced by BotBuilder python library in 4.12.0(when we found this issue first time), 4.14.0(currently version in PROD) and 4.14.2(the latest released version for today, April 27, 2022). This issue still can be reproduced in latest version 4.14.2. Here is the link about the most recently release version information.
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python

Comment: Could you please share if there is any Python sample/documentation you are following?

Comment: Maybe you can start with this example. 

```https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/54.teams-task-module```

You can update `def on_teams_task_module_fetch` in file :
```https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/54.teams-task-module/bots/teams_task_module_bot.py```
to return an Adaptive Card. 

I returned an Adaptive Card by following the code (to be continued in the next comment.)

Comment: `if task_module_request.data.get("message_type") == "no_data_found":
                task_info = TaskModuleTaskInfo()
                self.utilities.set_task_info(
                    task_info, TaskModuleUIConstants.REPORT_ISSUE_NO_DATA_FOUND)
                task_info.title = task_module_request.data.get("message")
                task_info.card = self.report_issue.get_no_data_found_comment_card(query_id)
                return TaskModuleResponseFactory.to_task_module_response(task_info)`

Comment: The key issue is, that the error should happen before the logic goes into function `on_teams_task_module_fetch`. Don't worry too much about the content inside `on_teams_task_module_fetch`.

Comment: Thanks for the steps, we are looking into it.

Comment: My apologies for the delay in responding. We tried to setup 54.teams-task-module python sample. While clicking on the buttons we get unable to reach app error in iOS. Can you please confirm if you are also seeing the same issue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9m5z.jpg